# bundle conflict with ruby default gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, bundler

I'm make a rails server env in Docker.
the docker file like this :

```
FROM ruby:2.6.3-buster
...
ADD Gemfile /app/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock
RUN gem install bundler -v 2.1.4
RUN gem install rake -v 13.0.1
RUN pwd
RUN bundle install # --full-index
CMD ["/bin/bash","./start-server.sh"]
```

then I go into container to test:

```
root@b3e642a78277:/app# bundle exec rails c
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:312:in `check_for_activated_spec!': You have already activated stringio 0.0.2, but your Gemfile requires stringio 0.1.4. Since stringio is a default gem, you can either remove your dependency on it or try updating to a newer version of bundler that supports stringio as a default gem. (Gem::LoadError)
root@b3e642a78277:/app#     from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:147:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:147:in `each'
    ....
```

Seems the default gems conflict with what installed by bundler.

when I check the gem list in container :

```
root@b3e642a78277:/app# gem list|grep string
stringio (default: 0.0.2)
root@b3e642a78277:/app# bundle exec gem list|grep string
stringio (0.1.4)
```

Seems bundle use default gems instead of installed in bundler.

How can I ask bundle DO NOT use default gems ?

Comment: try adding `RUN gem update --system` before `RUN gem install bundler`